# Simple table. Difficult request

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table:

```
level      box
1           1
2           2
3           2
1           3
2           1
2           3
2           3
3           1
```

How can I get this table with MySQL query?

```
         box1     box2         box3
level1    1        0            1
level2    1        1            2
level3    1        1            0
```

I have a big table so request should be fast.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the number of boxes fixed?

Comment: Yes. Only 3 boxes and 3 levels. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should do it, although there may be a more efficient method or one not requiring an aggregate.

**Edit**: Initially I misunderstood the requirement. Changed the `MAX()` aggregate to `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT('level', level) AS levelname,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN box = 1 THEN box ELSE NULL END) AS box1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN box = 2 THEN box ELSE NULL END) AS box2,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN box = 3 THEN box ELSE NULL END) AS box3
FROM tbl
GROUP BY levelname
```

Another method using `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT('level', a.level) AS levelname,
  b1.num AS box1,
  b2.num AS box2,
  b3.num AS box3
FROM
  table a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT level, COUNT(*) AS num FROM table WHERE box = 1) b1 ON a.level = b1.level
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT level, COUNT(*) AS num FROM table WHERE box = 2) b2 ON a.level = b2.level
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT level, COUNT(*) AS num FROM table WHERE box = 3) b3 ON a.level = b3.level
```

Comment: Don't you want COUNT(), not MAX()?

Comment: @CAbbott It doesn't matter if there aren't duplicates.  But if there are dupes (as it appears in the sample data), `SUM()` will return a different result set.  For example, the value of box 3 of level 2 would be 6 by `SUM()`, but is 3 by `MAX()`.

Comment: @CAbbott Actually, I misunderstood the requirement - it should be `COUNT()`.

Comment: I think the first solution will be faster?